# ¿Cómo reproducir un video desde un RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy utilizando un RecyclerView en mi aplicación y me gustaría poder reproducir un video, pero no encuentro forma de hacer eso en el mismo ítem del recycleview.

Comment: Reproducir un video es un poco amplio, ¿puedes especificar que player intentas utilizar? o ¿en que formato esta el video?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realizar esto no usaremos un RecyclerView sino un VideoView te redigire a un canal donde se encuentran dos videos donde te explico como realizar un cinturon de video y donde se expresa el codigo claramente:
Parte 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6MrBA-vDIc
Parte 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6xqo47MUzg